# Github API "reference already exists / StatusCode: 409" create-or-update-file-contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, github-api

I am trying to create file in github repo by reading current folder which has only 3 file. What I have notice that only one random file are getting create successfully and other return below error

```
data: {
  message: 'reference already exists',
  documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents'
}
```

although when I tried with postman, surprisingly there is no error at all.

```js
axios.put('https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php', {
    // sha: hash,
    committer: {
      name: "TEST NAME", 
      email: "test@test.com"
    },
    content: <base64_data>,
    message: "commit message",
    branch: "master"
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer <authKey>`,
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    }
  }
);
```

Error Stack

```
Error: Request failed with status code 409
    .........
    
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php',
    method: 'put',
    data: '{"committer":{"name":"Something Name","email":"test@test.com"},"content":"<base64_Data>","message":"Commit Message","branch":"master"}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      Authorization: 'Bearer <auth-key>',
      ContentType: 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.20.0',
      'Content-Length': 372
    },
    params: {},
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function],
      abort: [Function],
      aborted: [Function],
      connect: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.github.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.github.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 568,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.github.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.github.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 568,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'PUT /repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer <auth-key>\r\n' +
      'ContentType: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.20.0\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 372\r\n' +
      'Host: api.github.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object]
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'PUT',
    path: '/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 409,
      statusMessage: 'Conflict',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php',
      redirects: []
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 372,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      _currentRequest: [Circular],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php'
    },
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      contenttype: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 409,
    statusText: 'Conflict',
    headers: {
      date: 'Tue, 25 Aug 2020 17:18:29 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '136',
      connection: 'close',
      server: 'GitHub.com',
      status: '409 Conflict',
      'x-oauth-scopes': 'delete_repo, repo',
      'x-accepted-oauth-scopes': '',
      'x-github-media-type': 'github.v3',
      'x-ratelimit-limit': '5000',
      'x-ratelimit-remaining': '4984',
      'x-ratelimit-reset': '1598377957',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload',
      'x-frame-options': 'deny',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
      'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
      'content-security-policy': "default-src 'none'",
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With',
      'x-github-request-id': 'F3BA:2E97:CF7EE3:116C291:5F4547E4'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php',
      method: 'put',
      data: '{"committer":{"name":"Something Name","email":"test@test.com"},"content":"<base64_Data>","message":"Commit Message","branch":"master"}',
      headers: [Object],
      params: {},
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'PUT /repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer <auth-key>\r\n' +
        'ContentType: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.20.0\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 372\r\n' +
        'Host: api.github.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'PUT',
      path: '/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: {
      message: 'reference already exists',
      documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents'
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

I am using nodejs, axios. thank you.

Comment: Not very sure but, seems your URL is pointing to index.php, can you cross check URL used in Postman and also with Postman all 3 files get uploaded?

Comment: Yes, all three files are getting uploaded with no error. and index.php is the path variable, not the actual URL. /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}

Comment: I am talking about {path} part of URL in last comment, (i know index.php is not URL) can you copy paste working URL from Postman to code and test

Comment: what I have used in postman I put here except some private info.please tell me what u need specifically

Comment: Everything seems to correct i was wondering if theres any typo while hitting from Postman and from code, but seems you have cross checked it.

Comment: Yes, I have cross-checked. I am unable to find any clue.

Comment: @sp_kolinfure I tried this out and everything works perfectly. I tried to get all kind of messages but none of them is 'reference already exists'. I also cannot find this error. Could you show your whole result from axios and not only the data portion?

Comment: @LaurentDhont I have added error stack, Please look,

Comment: @LaurentDhont try to upload two files in a loop. One file will succeed but in my case, one file gets failed.

Comment: @sp_kolinfure I added an answer, if it doesn't work I will look some more. Thanks for your loop hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite certain this is because you do not wait for a request to finish and this is causing issues in the repository.

You can solve this by using an async function and awaiting the requests:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function main() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            const response = await axios.put('https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/index.php', {
                committer: {
                    name: "TEST NAME",
                    email: "test@test.com"
                },
                content: "SSBhbSB0cnlpbmcgdG8gaGVscCB5b3Uh",
                message: "commit message",
                branch: "master"
            }, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer <token>',
                    ContentType: 'application/json'
                }
            });
            console.log(response.data);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e.response.data);
        }
    }
}

main();
```

I hope this helped

Comment: does this work at your end? because my Axios is in await mode too and sleep time of 5 second. I will share my code tomorrow.

Comment: @sp_kolinfure Yes it works, but of course I get the 'Invladid request. "sha" wasn't defined' error because the file already exists. I still couldn't find the 'reference already exists' error but I did get 'is at 'sha' but expected 'othersha'' if I didn't await the promises in a loop.

Comment: Please create a scenario, where create a repo and try to push two file index.php and readme.md with the proper name. you don't need sha while creation, right. and then check what happen.

Comment: I don't know if something happened with the head of the branch.

Comment: Timing is not a problem I think. I use 30-second sleep time. the first request failed and the second request gets success. I am exhausted.

Comment: I found the issue, its basically async malfunction. synchronization not working. I use for loop rather forEach. and modified some logic. It's working now. THanks

Comment: @sp_kolinfure Ok, great. Did the answer provide a solution? If so, please accept it.